# Call activity method from conductor

Tags: android, kotlin, conductor

I have an Activity with a `zsmb:materialdrawer` and `conductor`

```
class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)
        router = Conductor.attachRouter(this, container, savedInstanceState)
        if (!router.hasRootController()){
            router.setRoot(RouterTransaction.with(HomeController()))
        }
    }

    fun addDrawerItem() {
        // not implemented
    }

    private fun initViews(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        toolbarMenu.setTitle(R.string.menu_title)

        drawerResult = drawer {

            primaryItem(getString(R.string.public_chats)){
                identifier = 101
                icon = R.drawable.abc_ic_star_black_48dp
                onClick(pushController(ChatRoomsController()))
            }
            primaryItem(getString(R.string.private_chats)){
                identifier = 102
                icon = R.drawable.abc_ic_star_black_48dp
                onClick(openActivity(ChatListActivity::class))
            }

        }
    }

}

class HomeController: Controller() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup): View {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_sign_in, container, false)
        val signInWithGoogle = mView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.sign_in_with_google)
        signInWithGoogle?.setOnClickListener({
            // handle action with drawer here
            // mView.addDrawerItem()
        })
        return mView
    }
}
```

And I want to call my `Activity` method from the `conductor`.
I'm trying to execute `mView.addDrawerItem()` but this method is not available there.
As I know `conductor` is a replacement for a fragment and in `fragment` I can easily call `activity` method through the `interface`. What is the best practice to do it in `conductor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conductor Controllers have a `getActivity()` method just like Fragments do. You'd do it the same whether you're using a Controller or a Fragment.

Comment: and is it a good idea to do getActivity.addDrawerItem()? When I use fragment I use interface which I pass through onAttach method. But OnAttach in Conductor doesn't have a context parameter and I can not initialize listener there.

Comment: In that case, use `onContextAvailable`. This is called when the context is very first available to the Controller and is analogous to a Fragment's `onAttach`. You can use the same interface you were using before.

Comment: I think you answered my question.